# An integral inequality using duality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am wondering if there is a more elementary proof of an inequality I found while reading a paper about minimal surfaces.

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be smooth, $Df(x)$ be its gradient, and $Q=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:|x^i|\le 1/2\}$ be the unit cube.  Suppose we have a smallness bound on the "excess" functional (vertical part of the area):
$$
\int_Q\sqrt{1+|Df|^2}dx-\int_Q dx\le E.\qquad (*)
$$
Here, $E< 1$.  Then this implies a small $W^{1,1}_0$ bound on the graph:
$$
\int_Q|Df|dx\le 2\sqrt{E}.\qquad (**)
$$
Is there a (more) elementary proof of $(**)$ (possibly modulo some constant independent of $E$)?  Here is the proof I have seen:

**Proof using $L^2$ duality:**

Applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to each point $x$, we see that
$$
\int_Q\sqrt{1+|Df(x)|^2}dx=\sup_{a(x)^2+|b(x)|^2\le 1}\int_Q\left(a(x)+b(x)\cdot Df(x)\right)dx,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ range over smooth functions such that $a^2+|b|^2\le 1$. The sup is attained when we choose $a=1/\sqrt(1+|Df|^2)$ and $b=Df/\sqrt(1+|Df|^2)$.   If we then make use of this in $(*)$, we get
$$
\int_Q (a-1+b\cdot Df)dx\le E.
$$
Choose $a=1-\tau$, where $\tau\in(0,1)$ is constant:
$$
\int_Q (b\cdot Df)dx\le E+\tau.
$$
Here, $b\in C^\infty(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^n)$ is arbitrary subject to $|b|^2\le 2\tau-\tau^2$ for $\tau\in(0,1)$, so taking the supremum in $b$ gives:
$$
\sqrt{2\tau-\tau^2}\int_Q|Df|dx\le E+\tau.
$$
Choosing $\tau=E$:
$$
\int_Q|Df|dx\le\sqrt{\frac{2E}{1-E/2}}.
$$
Applying $E<1$ to the denominator gives the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ is convex, hence we can apply Jensen's inequality (note that the cube heas measure $1$)
$$g\left( \int_Q|Df|\mathrm dx \right)
\le \int_Q g(|Df|)\mathrm dx = \int_Q \sqrt{1+|Df|^2}\mathrm dx \le E + 1.
$$
Rearranging yields
$$
\int_Q|Df| \mathrm dx \le \sqrt{E^2 + 2\,E}
$$
and for $E \in (0,1)$ this implies your inequality.
Moreover, this inequality is sharp for $|Df| = \mathrm{const}$.